# Android App (Flutter) is crashing with appbundle but runs in debug mode on both Devices and Emulators

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation

i am facing a strange issue.

My App keeps running in debug mode on a Huawei P20 and on all emulators but when i upload the Appbundle .aab to Play Store and test it on the Huawei , it crashes within splash screen loading.
Logcat does not give any useful insights.

You can also test the appbundle here -->

https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4700551316486574412

Comment: i Fixed it with reinstalling Android SDK and SDK Tools in the Preferences of Android Studio